# FTP using Explicit SSL/TLS on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ftps

I am developing an iPhone app. In which I have to upload Image on FTP server. For this, I have to use **(iOS) FTP using Explicit SSL/TLS** . I have searched a lot and found **Chilkat library**. There are no questions related to **Chilkat Library** on Stack Overflow. I don't want to use this as it is a paid library. If any another library is available that is free, please recommend, and give me a usage example.

Comment: http://www.example-code.com/ios/ftp_AuthTLS.asp Try it...

Comment: @Immi I dont want to use this

Comment: there are lots of question in chilkat library for iOS...what is ur doubt...let us know..